# AP twisted fate skill level up order

Tags: league-of-legends

> Wild cards (Q):(Active) Twisted Fate fires 3 cards forward in a cone, passing through targets and dealing magic damage to enemy units in their way.
>
> Pick a card (W):(Active) Cards flash over Twisted Fate's head in the following order: blue, then red, then gold, then blue again, starting randomly with any of the three and then continuing this pattern. When he uses the ability again, he picks the current card over his head, and the card picked adds a special effect to his next attack. This attack cannot miss or be dodged.
>
> Stacked deck (E):(Passive) Twisted Fate gains bonus attack speed and cooldown reduction. In addition, every fourth autoattack will deal bonus magic damage.

Which of these abilitys should I level up in the beginning and what would be the general skill order that a good tf player would pick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. For utility, I would start with Pick a card. The stun will be really useful early, for ganks and escape.
2. Then, you will want to max out Wild cards, as your primary damage source.
3. At level 4, one point in Stacked deck for the passive. Only one point, though, and you will max it only at the end.
4. Of course, a point in the ultimate whenever it is possible.

To summarize, **R > Q > W > E**

Comment: *Of course, this is not the only way to go, remember to adapt skill order, builds, etc according to your way of playing, and to the enemy. Don't follow builds blindly.*

Answer (score 1):

I would always recommend starting with Pick A Card, as it provides a stun (yellow card), a slow (red card), or gives mana (blue card).  Wild Cards should generally be picked next, as it has the most damage and range of all his abilities.  Finally, pick up Stacked Deck at lvl 3 for it's great passive.  You'll do slightly more damage picking Stacked Deck at lvl 3 instead of another rank in Wild Cards.

TF's basic combo is to auto attack until he has the bonus damage from Stacked Deck available.  Wait until your opponent gets into auto attack range, slow or stun them (Pick a Card), and hit them with Wild Cards.  This allows you to deal damage with all 3 abilities in under a second!

If you're building straight AP, Wild Cards has the best base damage and AP ratio (.65 vs .4).  If you're building on-hit items (Malady, Wit's End, etc), it may be better to maximize Stacked Deck first.  If you're having trouble sustaining in lane, an extra point or two into Pick a Card helps to regain mana.